# powershell add a computed column to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have this json which have to convert to an array and then add a column with values that i found in that json based on a key

```
$SomeJson = '[
                            {
                                "FullInstanceName":  "ServerName\\InstName",
                                "AGName":  "SomeAGName-1",
                                "CurrentRole":  "PRIMARY",
                                "SyncHealthDesc":  "HEALTHY"
                            },
                            {
                                "FullInstanceName":  "ServerName\\InstName",
                                "AGName":  "SomeAGName-2",
                                "CurrentRole":  "SECONDARY",
                                "SyncHealthDesc":  "HEALTHY"
                            },
                            {
                                "FullInstanceName":  "ServerName\\InstName",
                                "AGName":  "SomeAGName-3",
                                "CurrentRole":  "SECONDARY",
                                "SyncHealthDesc":  "NOT_HEALTHY"
                            }
]
'
$KeyName = "FullInstanceName,AGName"
$lpk = $KeyName.Split(",")
$lpk
$SomeJson | ConvertFrom-Json `
| Select-Object *, `
@{Name = 'KeyValue'; Expression = {"["+$_.FullInstanceName+"].["+$_.AGName+"]"} }
```

which gives me the desired result of

```
FullInstanceName : ServerName\InstName
AGName           : SomeAGName-1
CurrentRole      : PRIMARY
SyncHealthDesc   : HEALTHY
KeyValue         : [ServerName\InstName].[SomeAGName-1]

FullInstanceName : ServerName\InstName
AGName           : SomeAGName-2
CurrentRole      : SECONDARY
SyncHealthDesc   : HEALTHY
KeyValue         : [ServerName\InstName].[SomeAGName-2]

FullInstanceName : ServerName\InstName
AGName           : SomeAGName-3
CurrentRole      : SECONDARY
SyncHealthDesc   : NOT_HEALTHY
KeyValue         : [ServerName\InstName].[SomeAGName-3]
```

this value of `$KeyName` will be different each time i parse this json for e.g. next time it can be "AGName,DBName"
so in the expression, `@{Name = 'KeyValue'; Expression = {"["+$_.FullInstanceName+"].["+$_.AGName+"]"} }`
next time I want `@{Name = 'KeyValue'; Expression = {"["+$_.AGName+"].["+$_.DBName+"]"} }`

how can I achieve this, on the fly, just based on the value found in `$KeyName`

i tried creating an expression

```
$exp = "`"[`""
foreach ($n in $lpk) {
$exp+= "`+`$_.$n+`"].[`""
}
$exp = $exp -replace ".{5}$"
$exp+="`"]`""
$exp
```

and then pass this to the column `@{Name = 'LogicalPKValue'; Expression = {$exp} }`
which does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're going to use the same syntax to define your `$KeyName` variable, then you can change `FullInstanceName` for the index `0` and `AGName` for the index `1` of the `$KeyName` array to reference them dynamically.

```bash
$KeyName = "FullInstanceName,AGName".Split(',')

$SomeJson | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'KeyValue'
    Expression = {
        "[{0}].[{1}]" -f $_.($KeyName[0]), $_.($KeyName[1])
    }
}
```

If you're dealing with multiple values then you could use a loop:

```bash
Expression = {
    $tokens = foreach($key in $KeyName) {
        '[{0}]' -f $_.$key
    }
    $tokens -join '.'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, sorry forgot to mention that the number of values in the key can also be dynamic i.e. not always 2, can be 1 to 4. how can I handle that ?

Comment: thanks - i thought i did the big  ✓ button. just did it